# Format phone number on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, format

I need to enter a mobile number in a edit field.  I need to display the number in this format:
 `123-456-7890`

For example: 1234567890 is my mobile number, while am entering this into the text field,
after the first 3 digits I need to place a '-', after the next 3 digits, I need to place another '-'.

If I enter 123 then automatically place '-' in text field, after 456 place another '-' ,no need of placing for the last 4 digits.

Seems similar to displaying text in currency format, but when getting text from that text field I need to get the actual mobile number without any '-' ("1234567890", not 123-456-7890)
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: ok. After every key press, check the string in the field based on your conditions. if you want to append, just do a=a+"-"; were a is a string in the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code,

```
 public MyScreen()
{        
    setTitle("MyTitle");
    final EditField  ef = new EditField();
    add(ef);
    ef.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() 
    {
        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
        {

             if (ef.getText().length() == 4 && !ef.getText().endsWith("-"))
             { 
                    ef.setText(""+ef.getText().substring(0,3)+"-"+ef.getText().charAt(3));
            }
             if (ef.getText().length() == 8 && !ef.getText().endsWith("-"))
             { 
                    ef.setText(""+ef.getText().substring(0,7)+"-"+ef.getText().charAt(7));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add Listener on EditFiled and check length of entered phoneno ans set "-" at 3 and 7 position see following code may be help full.

```
editField.getEditField().setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() { 

            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                EditField sfield = (EditField)field;
            String number = sfield.getText();
            if (number.length() == 3 || number.length() == 7) { 
                setFormat(number); 
            } 
            } 

            });

    add(editField);
```

Create follwoing method on mainscreen class

```
private void setFormat(String newPhoneNo){
    editField.setText(newPhoneNo+"-");
}
```

Whenever you gettext form edit remove "-".

Answer (score -1):

Try out by trying first the native TextField.PHONENUMBER constraint.

```
public void startApp()
    {
        mDisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);
        mTextField = new TextField("Text Field Label:",null,MAXCHARS,TextField.PHONENUMBER);
        mForm = new Form("MIDlet Developer Guide: Display a text field.");
        mForm.append(mTextField);
        mDisplay.setCurrent(mForm);
    }
```

Comment: This answer looks like it's using vanilla J2ME Midlet code.  I think the poster probably wants to use BlackBerry UI libraries.  Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Not sure... I couldn't get it from the question

Comment: the above answer doesnt give like "123-456-7890". it will only give "1234567890"